# Как использовать matches чтобы найти name?

Tags: javascript

Как использовать matches чтобы вернуло true  ?

```js
var a = document.querySelector('.href');
console.log(a);
var a2 = a.matches('name');
var a3 = a.matches('ad');
console.log(a2);
console.log(a3);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="href" name='ad'></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = document.querySelector('.href');
console.log(a);
var a2 = a.matches('a[name]');
var a3 = a.matches("a[name='ad']");
console.log(a2);
console.log(a3);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="href" name='ad'></a>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в первой консоли значение null; в второй консоли значение error

Comment: @Leks однако, странно. Мой скрин выше)

Comment: Вы забыли вставить html код :) потому и написал в комменты

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Выберем элемент.
var link = document.querySelector('.href');

// Перебор "доступных" селекторов `css`.
var matches = {
    'тег': link.matches('a'),
    'атрибут href': link.matches('[href="#"]'),
    'атрибут name': link.matches('[name="ad"]'),
    'класс': link.matches('.href'),
    'вымышленный id': link.matches('#link')
}

// Распечатаем результат.
result.textContent = JSON.stringify(matches, null, 2);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="href" name="ad"></a>

<pre id="result"></pre>
```

---

**Справка** по [атрибутивным](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) и [другим](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_Selector#General_knowledge) селекторам.